# Mvc file Stream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, stream, download

Whether it is possible to know how much data user received when I return fileStrem in Controller ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream` instead of `HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs()`and manually save the file from input stream, you can get the upload progress.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand but if you want to get the size of the uploaded file in a controller action you could use the [ContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contentlength.aspx) property:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        // get the size of the file
        int size = file.ContentLength;
        // TODO: do something with the size

        // Saving the uploaded file
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If on the other hand your controller action is transferring some file to the client:

```
public ActionResult Download() 
{
    return File("foo.pdf", "text/pdf");
}
```